# How get text just from one element which is next dynamicly jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, next.js

I have a problem with this code. I tried so much codes before but everytime happends like a one code everytime I append new button with the same every element texts or in another way nothing works for me.

$j is my variable for jquery newer version because I must use both of them.

I need this...everytime I click on li element get text from just one next li element what is below of him and set this text into new button which will be also addeable how it is in below code after if, else.

this is my html code but not full of my code because some elements I create from Json with getting datas from it.

My html code is like this

```
<div>


<ul>
    <li class="match game-finished">date
        <ul>
            <li>match</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="match game-finished">date
        <ul>
            <li>match</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="match game-finished">date
        <ul>
            <li>match</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="match not-finished">date
        <ul>
            <li>match</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="buttons">
    <button id="close"></button>
</div>
```

So it will works just with this code in $

```
$j('.match').click(function () { 
            let finMatch = $j(this).next().text();
            if ($j(this).hasClass('game-finished')) { 
                $j('#new-btn').addClass('ui-btn-new');
                $j('.start-time').css({ fontSize: 1 + 'em' });
                $j('.start-date').css({ fontSize: 1 + 'em' });
                $j('#buttons').append('<button>' + finMatch + '</button>');
                $j('button').addClass('clicked');
            }
            else {
                $j('#new-btn').removeClass('ui-btn-new')
                
            }
        });
```

and with this code below works fine for me but if I clicked on last element in li with class date then there is not a text. I know why but I cant figure out how to do it correct.

```
$j('#close').click(function () { 
            $j('.clicked').remove();
        });
```

I tried this but it will not gonna works fine for me.

```
$j('.events').each(function () { 
            let find = $(this).find('.match').filter('.game-finished');
            console.log(find);
            let finMatch = find.next().text();
            find.click(function () { 
                $j('#buttons').append('<button>' + finMatch + '</button>');
                $j('button').addClass('clicked');
            });
        });
```

But everytime wrote me a some bad data not the correct data.

If somebody can help I will appreciate.
Also if somebody has a good idea how to sort already sorted li elements just by time then I will appreciate also.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

There's three main issues in your code. Firstly, your use of `$('.match)` in the click handler is selecting ***all*** the `.match` elements, not the one which was clicked. To do that, change the code to `$(this)`.

Secondly, you only define the `finMatch` variable in the true section of the `if` block, but it's used in both. Therefore you need to move its definition outside of the `if` statement.

Lastly, the `remove()` method expects a selector string of the element to be removed, not a HTML string to be created. You need to amend the logic to find the button with the matching text value, which can be done by using `filter()` and then call `remove()` on that.

Here's a working example with the above fixes applied:

```js
const $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j('.match').click(function() {
  let finMatch = $j(this).next().text();

  if ($j(this).hasClass('game-finished')) {
    /* removed non-relevant lines */

    $j('#buttons').append('<button>' + finMatch + '</button>');
  } else {
    $j('#new-btn').removeClass('ui-btn-new');
    $j('#buttons button').filter(el => el.textContent == finMatch).remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="match game-finished">A</li>
    <li class="match game-finished">B</li>
    <li class="match game-finished">C</li>
    <li class="match not-finished">D</li>
    <li class="match not-finished">E</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="buttons"></div>
```

Comment: you can help again if you know how. I edited my post because I forgot something.